# Text appearing after table overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I have some text, that should appear before a table, but instead appears after.

Do you have an idea why this is happening?

```
\section{Difference between serverless functions and containers}

Container technology and server-less functions have emerged as technologies that both attempt to achieve the goal of being small self-contained units with one responsibility, but where do they actually differ?

Some of the main differences are

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Serverless Functions}                                   & \textbf{Container}                             \\ \hline
    Scales automatically                                   & Requires management and orchestration \\ \hline
    You can't install software (like Webserver, Appserver) & You can install software              \\ \hline
    No attached hard disk                                  & Hard Disks attached to nodes          \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code, not just a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: `table` is a float. And thus gets moved around to where most appropriate. BTW: always add a caption to a float, and refer to the float by `\label` and `\ref` never by "on the table below..."

Comment: @MS-SPO Sorry, here you go.

Comment: If it is a small table and you don't want it to float, then don't use `\begin{table}...\end{table}`.